# Keras, how to get predict with model with removed last layer

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, keras, layer

Suppose I have dataset 100k x 400. I created this model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, input_dim = 400, init = init_weights))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(SReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(200, init = init_weights))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(SReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear', init = init_weights))
```

Than I call

```
model.compile(loss = ..
```

And

```
model.fit(input_matrix,..
```

After training I can call model.predict(.. for predictions.

What I would like to get is prediction matrix from model without last linear layer..

So something like:

```
model.remove_last_layer
pred_matrix = model.predict(input_matrix)
```

where output is 100k x 200 array, how can I do this with keras? thx a lot

Comment: Do you have your model trained?

Comment: yes, I got it trained

Comment: What is your `backend` and could you print `model.summary()`?

Comment: Check the docs, this might help you out: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer

Comment: thx for the link

Answer (score 5):

thx to the link to docs I found this

```
layer_name = 'dropout_2'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(input = model.input, output = model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(matrix_test)
```

Comment: In TF2 the arguments to `Model()` are `inputs` and `outputs` if it helps anyone.